# Paperclip S3 PDF Thumbnails do not load in IE7/8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, internet-explorer-8, amazon-s3, paperclip

This issue is an odd one. Our site allows users to upload PDFs using RoR & Paperclip and uploads the thumbnail as an attached file of the PDF to Amazon s3.

It works great, in every browser except IE7 and IE8. Most of the time, it works fine even in these browsers. There are a couple instances (differing only by PDF), however, where the image will not display (red x). Only in IE7 and 8 - even these "trouble" instances display fine in all other browsers.

Initially I was under the impression that this is probably because of the content_type of the attachments (since they were being served as application/pdf), although after fixing to the right type (image/jpeg) the problem endured.

The properties in IE8 of the image states it's type as "Not Available", if it matters.

Anyways, is anyone aware of this issue or have any idea or avenue to explore... What could cause a jpeg image to not be served in ie7/8 but everything else? I've searched quite heavily to no avail and this is scary. (**shakes fist at IE**)